# Why "Google Translate" instead of "Google Translation/Translator"?

Tags: vocabulary, names

Why has Google named  its translation service "Google Translate"? Wouldn't "Google Translation" or "Google Translator" be more natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is marketing, not grammar.  Verbs convey a feeling of action, by definition, so by using the verb **translate**, Google is hoping to emphasize that they're *doing something*.  In theory, this makes their translation service sound more exciting and/or emphasizes that translation is a lot of work.

For very similar reasons, many people recommend that your résumé or CV should describe your work experience using verbs, which shows dynamic action on your part.

Comment: There is a semantic reason for it which has nothing to do with marketing.

Answer (score 2):

The name is in a commercial style which deliberately seeks to add "pizzazz" to product names.  The verb connotes *action*.

It would not be surprising to find a Google app about city transportation schedules called *Google Commute*, or an iOS app about local restaurants called *i-Eat* or *i-Dine*.

Answer (score 1):

It is Google Translate because it translates stuff for you. It is not a finished product.

The German translation of Gone with the Wind = a finished text.

The translation of the Bible into Russian = a finished text.

**Google Translation** for the online application would be a misnomer.

However, people will often cite a poor Google translation as "proof of x, y or z".